# sed s command with only one slash "/"

Tags: shell, sed

```
echo "en_Us" | sed "s._./."  # returning en/Us
```

I recently encounter a sed command like above, I am not 100% sure why, according to "man sed", s command usually comes like

```
sed "s/regex/regex"
```

to replace the the matched regex, in this case, it only has one slash, what does that mean ?

Comment: In short, it is using a different delimiter here, just like /, since we are going to substitute "_" to "/", using "." as delimiter frees as to use escape characters, if using "/" as delimiter, it should be written as 
echo "en/Us" | sed "s/_/\//"

Answer (score 0):

`echo "en_Us" | sed "s._./."` is almost equal to `echo "en_Us" | sed "s#_#/#"` which means it is the for a word before first occurence of "*" and substitute with "/". If you want replace all "*"s use the "g" (group) as `echo "en_Us" | sed "s._./.g"`